# No lock screen option for certain user

Tags: 12.04, lock-screen

I seem to have lost the `lock screen` option for one user of the system. It does not appear in the menu in the top right hand corner (with `Log Out` etc) and nor does `Ctrl+Alt+L` do anything despite being listed in the keyboard shortcuts of my system settings to lock screen. If I go to `Brightness and Lock` the lock area is just greyed out.

This facility is available to other users on the system so I'm not quite sure what the problem is. I should note that this particular user is not an admin user and does not have `sudo` privileges whereas the user is works for does (just in case that is important).

I can't remember if I perhaps turned this facility off a long time ago for this user, but if so now I don't seem to be able to get it back.

Some things I've tried:

> Removed xscreensaver, re-installed gnome-screensaver (currently the newest version)
>
> Set `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true`
>
> I created a new test user with no admin privileges and for them the `lock screen` option was available.

Comment: Please make a test: create a new "normal" user and see if the lock-screen is enabled there. (and edit your question to tell us the result :-))

Comment: @guntbert I did as you asked and put result in my OP. The new test ``normal'' user did have `lock screen` availability.

Comment: So it looks like its a setting just for one user, not a system problem, no idea how to find that - sorry.

Comment: got the same issue suddenly by upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10. Affect a single no sudoer user...

Answer (score 1):

In the mean time I got some form of lock capability back by just purging `gnome-screensaver` reinstalling `xscreensaver` and adding a custom keyboard shortcut of `Ctrl+Alt+L` (after disabling the existing one in system) to launch the `xscreensaver-command --lock` command and lock my screen with that. I still don't have a `Lock Screen` in the drop down nor can I work out how I got rid of the original lock screen for this user.

Answer (score 1):

On my installation, the issue appeared when upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10

Found the solution by looking at another question :

[Screen truns off when I lock, but doesn't lock. "Lock" settings grayed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450077/screen-truns-off-when-i-lock-but-doesnt-lock-lock-settings-grayed-out)

I don't know why but the Unity Security option had disabled locking and user session on a non sudoer admin. Removing the option reenabled the locking and switching ability.