# Screen truns off when I lock, but doesn't lock. "Lock" settings grayed out

Tags: lock-screen, 14.04

I'm on trusty and I can't lock my computer by any means. When I press Super+L or use the Lock button in the panel, the behavior is the same: the screen turns black and if I move the mouse, my desktop pops up again, without ever locking.

I'm on Trusty x86 and I confirmed that if I create a new user account, I can lock the screen in that account. I checked the Lock settings in "Brightness & Lock" and everything is grayed out, as the following screen capture shows. How can I enable the usual system lock again?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you use Unity Tweak Tool? You might have this option enabled and not even know about it:

[image]

Comment: You're right. How did this get enabled in the first place? I re-enabled locking in UTT and now Ubuntu is locking smoothly again. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a separate home partition it might be because of old settings from previous versions. I'm not really sure.

Comment: I had the same problem, and could only fix it by installing this tool.  The tool could not have caused my issue, but it fixed it.

Comment: Same issue, same fix (install unity-tweak-tool and disable this option). Thanks!

Comment: same issue on a new install of 16.04 same solution

Comment: same. I think it's disabled by default for some reasons.